# Get request headers in azure functions NodeJs Http Trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, http, azure-functions

How do I get the request headers in Azure functions ? I use JavaScript http trigger to handle a request. I need to read some token sent in the request header from the front end. How can I do this ?

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    if (true) {
        context.log(req.headers['Authorization'])
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello there " 
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
    context.done();
};
```

Comment: can you post your code so we can look at it and help you out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `req.headers`, e.g.

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('Header: ' + req.headers['user-agent']);
    context.done();
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't find in any part of the documentation.

Comment: Note that the headers are in lower case i.e. `user-agent` instead of `User-Agent`

Answer (score 4):

You can also do something like this with the run time **context** also.

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    context.log(context.req.headers.authorization)//You can get the pass tokens here
    context.done();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wants the C#:

e.g.
To get the Authorization token:

```
log.Info(req.Headers.Authorization.Token.ToString());
```

More on the various headers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.headers.httprequestheadercollection).